# What are the good approaches for a ViewPager/PageAdapter to work with large number of view Fragments?

Tags: android, android-fragments, asynchronous

ViewPager/PageAdapter is an useful combination for an activity that deals with series of Fragments. The examples found via web search show a finite (and small) number of fragments. 
What if number of fragment is very large or unlimited (or unknown) to ViewPager/PageAdapter to begin with?

The other complexity is that the content of the fragments being shows are fetched from a remote service asynchronously.

Answer (score 0):

you can set dynamic view pager if you don't know the size using for loop

```
        String[] nameArray=getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs);            
        for(int 0;i<getResources().getStringArray(R.array.tabs).length;i++) 
        {
            name= nameArray[i];                
            expenseAdapter.addFrag(new DynamicFragment(), name);               
        }
```